# Pass data from IEnumerable to another IEnumerable C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

I have 2 iCollections as follows:-

ICollection 1

```
public class ClassA : List<ClassC>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var sdr = new SqlDataRecord(
            new SqlMetaData("A", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            );

        foreach (ClassC ei in this)
        {
            sdr.SetInt32(0, ei.A);

            yield return sdr;
        }
    }
}
```

ICollection 2

```
public class ClassB : List<ClassC>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var sdr = new SqlDataRecord(
            new SqlMetaData("A", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int),
new SqlMetaData("B", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            );

        foreach (ClassC ei in this)
        {
            sdr.SetInt32(0, ei.A);
sdr.SetInt32(0, ei.B);

            yield return sdr;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass the data of ClassB into ClassA i.e. ICollection 2 and ICollection 1?

Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

```
  ClassA a = new ClassA();
  ClassB b = new ClassB();
  // fill a and b
  a.AddRange(b);
```

Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Both have different number of parameters. We cannot add the range in this case.